# Teen secretly playing video games when should be doing homework

Tags: teen, age-appropriate, video-games, homework

If a son of about 14 years old, using his laptop to do schoolwork, secretly plays video games instead, should it be the parent's responsibility to find this out and stop him?

If the son finds it hard to resist playing video games when he should be doing homework, how (without getting in too much trouble!) can he talk to his parents about this issue and get help from his parents in developing the self-discipline he needs to get his schoolwork done?

Comment: You have a son while being only 14 yourself? Or is it that you want us to enumerate ways you could be caught? (If so, you might want to try Superuser.com.)

Comment: Try reevaluating your stance on video games and letting your son play them. An enterprising son would supply a parent with some of the research out there that shows moderate gaming can be quite beneficial.

Comment: @sbi Just ignore what my profile says, I never put the real one.

Comment: You have another recent question about preventing parental divorce, so I'm as confused as @sbi

Comment: @Erica in light of the previous question, I half suspect Bob is trying to covertly fish for advice in how to subvert parental controls.

Comment: Please, just answer the question.

Comment: Beyond the identity issues here - and given these two questions I think they're significant - *how* to track computer usage to this level is largely off-topic for Parenting; as recommended above, Super User would be potentially relevant, with a bit more detail.  As it stands the question is simply too lacking in detail to be answerable anywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tracking computer usage and would better be addressed on Superuser or a similar site.

Comment: I've heavily edited the question to make it more suitable for this site and to bring out what I think is the subtext. Revert if not happy. ;)

Comment: The computer savvy son should try on http://productivity.stackexchange.com/ - they deal with similar questions regularly. Perhaps the 14yo. could try to solve the problem himself as he seems to be quite capable?

Comment: See also: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/13765 although of course that doesn't cover the 'parental discipline versus self discipline' aspect.

Comment: Is it common that the OP also votes to close the question as "unclear what's being asked" ?

Comment: Bob, I suggest you are methodically about this and change your age from 14 to 56 _everywhere_, not just on a few sites. `:)` (For example, you forgot to change it [on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/111088/bob-the-zealot).) Otherwise, [CreationEdge's answer](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/18532/7982) is great for a 14yo.

Comment: @sbi Uh... I thought they all change when I change one :) I guess Area51 is an exception.

Comment: [That](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/18470/7982) still won't make me believe you're 50.

Comment: @sbi Honestly, this feels like a kid trying to find out how to get his parents to do their damn job without getting in trouble for previous offenses. Perfectly sensible to me.

Answer (score 7):

There is [research on the benefits of gaming](https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/amp-a0034857.pdf), and the parents should read it. If the child doesn't know about it, he can do some research and supply it to the parents.

If the son can calmly and politely explain his reasoning for wanting to play games, and demonstrate that he's done the research into why gaming can be good, then he may change his parents' minds.

If the parents allow their child to openly play video games, for a limited time, then they'd likely be eliminating their son's need for subversive behavior. Since he'd be allowed access to his laptop at times *other* than when doing homework, he'd be able to play without cutting into his homework time.

One of the import things the son will have to do as part of this discussion is **show that he can get his homework done** without it being an issue. If he's currently having trouble getting his homework done, his parents aren't likely going to "reward" him with video games. **He needs to demonstrate a level of maturity that shows he's willing to work for the things he wants**.

A great way to get homework done is to specifically schedule time in your day to work on your homework. Work somewhere that's as free of distractions as you can, and *plan* on doing homework.

While working on homework, break it up into manageable sections. You don't have to do everything in one straight block. Pick a goal that will take 15-20 minutes. Once you've finished that goal, take break: read some Facebook or Twitter, get up and walk, get a drink, watch a short YouTube video, whatever you're allowed to do. Then, after a couple minutes, get back to the homework and set another short goal.

Comment: Allow me to compliment you to answering this question the way you did. `+1` from me for answering the real question behind what was asked.