# How do I stop my parents' divorce?

Tags: behavior

I'm a new teen, and my parents have been fighting for like a month like five times a week.

One of them leaves at night for like six hours, my mom says she doesn't think it's working out. They have been married six years, and they sometimes fight like this, but never this bad.

I don't like pointing fingers but it's mostly my mom's fault.

How do I talk to her and stop this?

Comment: Please see http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/how-can-i-prevent-my-parents-divorce