# What can I do when my parents want a divorce?

Tags: parents, divorce

My mum and dad want a divorce and I don't know what I can do. My dad likes another woman and my mom already asked three lawyers for the divorce. My BFF has heard some things about this. My life is already a dark, gloomy cloud, and I am very very unlucky! I don't know what to do. Please Help Me!

Comment: "Please help me" is unclear as a question. Do you need support? Do you need to understand what's going on and why? Do you want to know what you can do to stop it? Who to live with after the divorce? These are all specific questions. But I see no question in your post. I didn't close it as unclear because I think the duplicate might help you. If it does not, please edit your post and flag for reopening. We are here to help, but we need to know what you're asking to give you a good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry but I do not know what we can do for you. Have you read other questions and answers? Here's one: [LINK](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/how-can-i-prevent-my-parents-divorce?rq=1)

The short answer is that you can't prevent it, only they can make this decision. You can talk to them. You can tell them how you feel. You're afraid, hurt, angry, upset, and worried about what will happen. They can answer these questions for you.

My advice is to try not to choose a side as it is unlikely that you will ever know all the details. No one is perfect and I'd bet both your parents have made mistakes and hurt each other. I am not suggesting that you lie or not share how you feel, but I also think that once you've expressed how you feel (believe me they already know), then just try to support both of them and any siblings you have.

You may have to help more around the house and help your parents to remember things. They have a lot going on. "Mum, I need that permission slip signed, please." "Dad, remember I need a lunch tomorrow, thanks."

You might find that you have to grow up a little more quickly, and think before you act. You might have to take on more responsibility. This will all work out in the long run even though it is hard right now.

Oh and regarding luck: You make your own happiness. You can decide to be a happy person. That doesn't mean bad stuff doesn't happen. It means you keep going and look for things that are good.