# What to do or how to feel if my parents want a divorce but say that it is my and my brothers fault also?

Tags: parents, divorce

What to do or how to feel if my parents want a divorce but say that it is my and my brother's fault also?

Comment: Hi Roberta. If you could give us some additional information, this question might not be closed and we might be able to give you some help. No one is able to tell you how to feel. How old are you? Your brother? Who blamed you and what did they say their reasoning was? Has this been going on for a long time? Are there other circumstances that might help us to understand?

Comment: Please add more detail. As it is now, it's much too broad. We'd really like to help, but we'd be just guessing. Use the edit button just under the tags. Thanks!

Comment: And omfg... it is *not* your fault nor your brother's fault!!  Divorce comes from the married people being incompatible, not the kids. Also, related: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/how-can-i-prevent-my-parents-divorce

Answer (score 5):

Your immediate overwhelming emotional reaction should be that your parents are completely wrong.

However, you should consider that you may have misunderstood what they said, and that they do not really think their children are in any way responsible for their problems, and they are suffering such intense agony that they are irrationally lashing out at everyone within reach.

Consider this: is there anybody that they are *not* blaming right now?

If you can, you should feel that everyone is emotionally upset beyond reason and nothing makes sense to anybody right now. After some time passes, your parents will calm down and begin to apologize to everyone around them.

In any case, their divorce is not your fault, and don't ever let anyone tell you that it is.

Comment: We have a Be Nice policy and you're violating it.

Comment: As pointed out to you, you can delete your user account, or dissociate your account from these posts, but you are not to delete them.