# What can I do to prevent my parents divorce?

Tags: parents, divorce

I’m a young teenager, younger than 16. My stepmom told my mother she wants a divorce, but they’ve been together for several years. My mom was accused of cheating, because my she went to a friends house and they told her they loved her. Now, I’ve known this friends since I was little, and that’s just how he talks. However, instead of talking the situation out with my mother, she demanded a divorce. I know they both love each other very much, and them being divorced will break my heart. Is there anything I can do from them to not get a divorce?

Comment: Have you read this similar question: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/how-can-i-prevent-my-parents-divorce?rq=1